# Can I play Spotify songs in my app, without the user logging in?

Tags: spotify

Is there a way to play Spotify songs in my app, using a token generated for my app, not for each user?

Comment: If technically possible, I wonder whether the license allows for this. Which is not a technical topic :)

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way to play Spotify songs in my app, using a token
>   generated for my app, not for each user?

Yes, but with a huge caveat. If your application starts playback of a track using an access token connected to a particular user with the `streaming` scope, it'll interrupt playback for any other instance of your application using an access token from the same user.

To clarify, in order to start playback your application needs to supply an access token with the `streaming` scope. The `streaming` scope can only be granted if a user gives your application permission. This means that the `streaming` scope is always connected to the user that has authorized the application.

Spotify allows a user to play music from a single device. If you're playing music from your Spotify desktop application, and try to start playback on the Spotify application on your mobile phone at the same time, the desktop application will stop automatically. The same type of interruption will occur if you're trying to start playback through your application using an access token connected to the same user.

The user must be a Spotify Premium subscriber - There's no support in the mobile SDKs for Spotify Free.

Comment: :(.
Do Spotify have some sort of "partner" account? I do not care about paying to let my users do that, I just care about finding a way for my users to play any song they want without having to subscribe/pay anything

Comment: No, there's not. Playback using the mobile SDKs require the user to be a Premium subscriber. There's simply no support for the ad-based Spotify Free.

Comment: So if I understand well, 1) I can't play full songs on more than 1 device at the same time with the same token 2) there are no special tokens to do that 3) I can still play previews of the song without token

Right?

Comment: Hey Brendan, did you figure out a way to do this? I want to be able to play mp3 files on my application without worrying about the infra to store these files.  Is there a way i can these files on Spotify and render them on my page using the Spotify API?